# Session cookies working under subdomain

Tags: php, session, cookies

How to get session cookies working / to be accessible under domain and subdomains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For session cookies you need to override the [cookie params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

So you can either use:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.website.com');
```

or

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.website.com');
```

The '.' in front makes it accessible under the domain and the subdomains.

Note: you will have to delete all existing cookies from your browser for the domain you're working with so they can be re-initialized properly to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the cookie for the "top" domain  (example.com), the cookie will also apply to subdomains  (sub.example.com, another.example.com).

As an aside, this is the reason why some larger companies use completely separate domains to serve static stuff, like stackoverflow uses http://sstatic.net/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using setcookie().  If so just set the cookie for ".domain.com".

```
setcookie("testcookie", "1", 0, "", ".domain.com");
```